# Substring error in StreamReader

Tags: c#, substring, streamreader, unity-game-engine

Hello I am having a trouble writing an editor for Unity3D and I ran into a problem where I am reading lines from a .txt file that has regular strings, and then file extensions below each regular strings (which represents categories for the extensions). The problem comes in when I try to run the substring on the string that is assigned to the next line. When I try using any substring, the file shows up as opened unsuccessfully, yet without it, opens just fine.

```
public bool PopulateList()
{
    bool success = true;
    string path = "Assets/Scripts/Editor/Extensions.txt";
    sourceFile = new FileInfo("Assets/Scripts/Editor/Extensions.txt");

    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        Debug.Log("File Does Not Exist");
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
        tw.Close();
    }
    string line;
    ExtensionUnit anExtension;

    try
    {
        StreamReader myStreamReader = sourceFile.OpenText();
        line = myStreamReader.ReadLine();

        while (!myStreamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            anExtension = new ExtensionUnit();

            anExtension.Categories = line;
            line = myStreamReader.ReadLine();

            /*if(line.Substring(0,1) == ".")
            {
                //Debug.Log(line.Substring(0, 1));
            }*/

            //Debug.Log(line.Substring(0, 1));
            /*while(line.Substring(0,1) == ".")
            {
                anExtension.Extensions = line;
                theExtensions.Add(anExtension);

                //Next extension
                line = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
            }*/

            //Empty blank space
            line = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
        }
        myStreamReader.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}
```

}

Comment: wellcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show example of the text file ?

Comment: can you not just simply use a TextAsset?

Comment: @JoeBlow I would use a Text Asset, but I am not using the Unity Engine Library, only using the Unity Editor Library

Answer (score 1):

Read all file data first, and then do all the logic (Substring e.t.c.)

```
  public bool PopulateList()
    {
        var success = true;
        var path = "Assets/Scripts/Editor/Extensions.txt";

        if (File.Exists(path))
           {
              try
                  {
                     var fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(path);

                     foreach (var line in fileContent)
                        {
                        // Define what lines do you need and get needed extensions 
                        }
                  }

              catch (Exception ex)
                  {
                    Log(ex); // it`s better to know the reason at least
                    success = false;
                  }
           }

       return succes;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it without opening the file:

```
StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(sourceFile.FullName);
```